# Make pip install package for specific Python installation

Tags: python, pip

I have two versions of Python 2.7.

Using `pip-2.7 install bsddb3` seems to install bsddb3 for the native OS X version of Python.

How do I change it to the version of Python located at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS
```

(Found the path with `>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` which might not be correct. *nix still confuses me.)

**Note** AFAICS this is not a duplicate. The other qs asks how to install for specific *versions* (e.g. 2.7 vs 2.6).

Comment: Yes, I wondered about that too, but that is where it was installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a virtualenv pointing at the python you want, using something like `virtualenv -p PYTHON_EXE VIRTUALENV_DIR`. Then activate that virtualenv with `source VIRTUALENV_DIR/bin/activate` and then running `pip` will be isolated and use the python of that virtualenv.

If you don't use virtualenv, start :)

Comment: Accepting this tentatively even though installing virtualenv seems to open another bag of cans of worms.

Comment: virtualenv can just be a single python script you download and run, if you want to not install it in any way - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv has the details.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't running pip with the python to which you want to install the package like this works?

```
path/to/python path/to/pip install package_name
```

btw, why not create new virtualenv and use pip from there?

Comment: Any permutation of those did not work, but I might not have understood what you tried to do.