# pip using Python 2.5 and need to use Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to install Django via pip, with

`pip install Django==1.5.5`

but I get the error:

```
File "django\utils\version.py", line 1
from __future__ import unicode_literals
SyntaxError: future feature unicode_literals is not defined
```

My guess is this is because pip is using the Python 2.5 version of pip.  I have installed pip into Python 2.7, and have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip
```

**Question:**  I know I can install Django from the .tar, but I would like pip to work so that other Python 2.7 projects can use the (much simpler) pip.  What do I need to change in order for this to work?

Comment: Have you tried using easy_install? Also, are you using a virtual env?

Comment: Looking into setting up virtualenv & virtualenvwrapper-win.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5226504/2689986) & [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472942/make-pip-install-package-for-specific-python-installation?rq=1) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your path is `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip`, I guess you're on Windows. Then which pip is invoked is controlled primarily by `%PATH%` system environment. Running `echo %PATH%` to find out which pip directory is listed first and changing variable appropriately should help. Normally, the directory you need to be searched first should be `C:\Python27\Scripts`, that is where `pip.exe` is located.

Comment: Thanks.  When I was looking for pip, I was looking for pip in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip for some reason.  What worked for me was to do:  C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install django==1.6